# Sending Parameters from MVC 4 Action to Web form for the SSRS report

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, reporting-services

i am using SSRS Report in my mvc4 web application
 using web form(reportviewer server side control in it ) and 
view (containing the iFrame).
i am sending parameters to report from my action using Session
here is my code.
 
Controllers action code

```
    public ActionResult GetParamReport()
    {
        HttpContext.Session.Add("param","a");
        Redirect("~/Contents/Reports/ReportParameter.aspx");
        return View("ParamReport");
    }
```

in my page load in aspx i access it using

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string Parameter = HttpContext.Current.Session["param"].ToString(); 
    }
```

is there any other alternative to send parameter other than session because i dont want to use session.

Comment: Have you consider sending it by QueryString?

Comment: @silagy off course i consider but i am not getting how to pass through the querystring to aspx and at the same time i want to return my view

Answer (score 0):

Passing it as query string is defiantly prefered:

```
public ActionResult GetParamReport()
{
    return Redirect("~/Contents/Reports/ReportParameter.aspx?param=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("some value"));
}
```

and then:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string parameter = Request["param"]; 
}
```

Comment: i want to return my view, anyway i tried above solution, this gives an error **Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.**

Comment: In this case return your view (`return View()`) and inside this view use an `<iframe>` with an `src` property pointing to your aspx page - `src="@Url.Content("~/Contents/Reports/ReportParameter.aspx")?param=@HttpUtility.UrlEncode("some value")"`.

Comment: that i already did , i mentioned in question, my concern here is i want to send parameters to my aspx from view

Comment: Sure, you could pass them as query string parameters when specifying the src of the iframe.

Comment: could you please tell me how can i pass in my action method ? i am taking parameter in my view from the user then i get it in my action method from there i need to pass it to web form page load

Comment: You could pass the parameter to the view as property to your view model.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25128/discussion-between-d-siva-and-darin-dimitrov)